# Datepicker comes twice when click first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my js code:

```
    $(function(){
       $(".datepicker").datepicker();
       $("#tarih").fadeIn();
    });
```

div:

```
    <div id="tarih" style="display:none;margin:auto;padding:10px">
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" maxlength="0" placeholder="Click to Schedule..." >
    </div>
```

where is my wrong?

Comment: I mostly beleive that the keypress event is causing the problem, could you create a jsfiddle so that i can check it once. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/3YQDV/2/

Comment: It's code somewhere else, the code and markup you posted works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/8TvZd/